# How can I change multiple filenames in different subdirectories in python?

Tags: python, subdirectory

I am working with Python3 and am trying to change the names of files in multiple subdirectories to match the folder name. My directory looks like this:

path: C:\Users\Me\Project
In the path, I have the following folders: alldata, folderA, folderB, folderC

FolderA, folderB, and folderC, each contain a file called data.csv

I want to add the letter name of the folder (e.g., A, B, C) to the file (e.g., dataA.csv) inside the folder and then move all these renamed files to "alldata"

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey, maybe you could post what you've tried so far?

Comment: folders= ['A','B','C']
for letter in folders:
    path = ('C:/Users/Me/Project/folder'+letter)
    oldfile = 'data.csv'
    newfile = 'data'+letter+'.csv'
    shutil.move(oldfile, newfile)

Comment: Clearly, I'm missing something major. I can't even figure out how to move everything to the alldata folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one might be a little hardcoded, but is probably more understandable for people who are just starting out in Python:

```
import os
import shutil

# Enter the 'Project' folder
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Me\\Project')
# Filter for folders that contain the word 'folder'
folders = [folder for folder in os.listdir() if 'folder' in folder]

for folder in folders:
    # Get the last letter of every folder
    suffix = folder[-1]
    # Build source and destination path for the csv files
    source = folder + '\\data.csv'
    dest = 'alldata\\data' + suffix + '.csv'

    shutil.move(source, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'os' module in python gives you access to functions that deal with folders and files. For example, there are functions in the os module to move, copy, rename, delete folders and files. Try this for example:

```
import os
basePath = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Project\\"

# Rename and move the data.csv file in folderA to dataA.csv in the alldata folder
os.rename(basePath + "folderA\\data.csv", basePath + "alldata\\dataA.csv")
# Rename and move the data.csv file in folderB to dataB.csv in the alldata folder
os.rename(basePath + "folderB\\data.csv", basePath + "alldata\\dataB.csv")
# Rename and move the data.csv file in folderC to dataC.csv in the alldata folder
os.rename(basePath + "folderC\\data.csv", basePath + "alldata\\dataC.csv")

# Make sure that they moved as intended
filesInAllDataFolder = os.listdir(basePath + "alldata\\")    
print(filesInAllDataFolder)
```

The os module is super handy and I guarantee you'll use it a lot, so play with it!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import os

def scan_dir(folder):
    for name in os.listdir(folder):
        path = os.path.join(folder, name)

        if os.path.isfile(path):
            if 'data' in path:
                dir_name = path.split('/')[-2]
                new_name_path = path[:-3]+dir_name+'.csv'      
                new_name_path = new_name_path.split('/')
                new_name_path[-2] = 'alldata'
                new_name_path = "/".join(new_name_path)
                os.rename(path, new_name_path)
       else:
            scan_dir(path)


directory = 'C:\Users\Me\Project'
scan_dir(directory)
```